Why was the client spooked when he saw the professor's face?
In Hit Man (2023), a client was spooked after seeing the professor's face at the diner. Why was the client spooked?
I thought the client was a student at the professor's university and recognized him, but I have no evidence for this.

The client is Ray, Madison's husband that previously confronted Gary (in his Ron persona).

He's just tried to hire Ron to kill "Ron/Gary"... of course he's spooked.
As Wikipedia says..

Gary and Madison have a heated encounter with Ray, Madison’s ex-husband, which ends with Gary pulling a gun to back Ray off.
Furious with Madison, Ray attempts to have her killed, unknowingly contacting Gary. Unable to research his suspect, Gary walks into the encounter blind, and improvises having their conversation with backs to each other. However, he reveals himself to Ray at the end of their conversation.


Ah. I'm bad with faces and the chat with the team in the next scene saying "some people are just spooked easily for no reason" did not help.

Since they both knew each other, then why wouldn't Ron play along until he accepted payment so Ray could be arrested?

Because then Ray would tell everyone that Gary/Ron was dating Madison and had pulled a gun on him.

That sounds like a "he said, she said" situation (and he has no reason to reveal that because dating someone and having a concealed firearm isn't illegal), which in my opinion is less dangerous than letting Ray go and allowing him to hire another hitman.
